# Opentok android Nativescript audio device crash on publish [RESOLVED]

Tags: android, nativescript, opentok, tokbox

I currently have an error with Opentok when using the Android SDK plugin (Nativescript-opentok). The SDK version is 2.17.+ using Maven and the plugin is from the NativeScript MarketPlace.

I am able to connect and I am also able to subscribe to another feed that use OpenTok JS 2.15.1, but when I publish with my android phone, OpenTok returns me a publisher error : Negotiation Timed Out, which is not in the OpenTok.Error object list, and it's never thrown by the SDK itself, but rather only visible in the Opentok Developer Inspector, which is on their website. I have access granted to my camera and microphone since I am able to see my own camera feed in the publisher view tag when I connect to the session.

Plus, my audio crashes the entire application.

I added an answer in order to make my question cleaner, is it related with audio permissions on my device ?

Adb logcat crash report :

```
05-26 12:16:40.157  1604  1747 F atrCompanionAp: java_vm_ext.cc:570] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetObjectClass called with pending exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Audio capture is not initialized 44100
05-26 12:16:40.157  1604  1747 F atrCompanionAp: java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean com.opentok.android.DefaultAudioDevice.initCapturer() ((null):-1)
```

... stack trace in-between

```
05-26 12:16:40.292  1604  1747 F atrCompanionAp: runtime.cc:630]   native: #28 pc 000000000043c9d8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+52)
05-26 12:16:40.292  1604  1747 F atrCompanionAp: runtime.cc:630]   native: #00 pc 000000000008033c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+28)
05-26 12:16:40.292  1604  1747 F atrCompanionAp: runtime.cc:630]   | held mutexes=
05-26 12:16:40.292  1604  1747 F atrCompanionAp: runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
05-26 12:16:40.292  1604  1747 F atrCompanionAp: runtime.cc:630]   native: #05 pc 00000000001db8d4  /data/app/org.nativescript.AvatrCompanionApp-vK0zREAM_BobIo-Eksgn2Q==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
05-26 12:16:40.292  1604  1747 F atrCompanionAp: runtime.cc:630]   (no managed stack frames)
05-26 12:16:40.293  1604  1747 F atrCompanionAp: runtime.cc:630]   (no managed stack frames)
05-26 12:16:40.293  1604  1747 F atrCompanionAp: runtime.cc:630]   native: #10 pc 00000000003582bc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::GetObjectClass(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+668)
05-26 12:16:40.293  1604  1747 F atrCompanionAp: runtime.cc:630]   native: #23 pc 0000000000084b6c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
05-26 12:16:40.293  1604  1747 F atrCompanionAp: runtime.cc:638] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetObjectClass called with pending exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Audio capture is not initialized 44100
```

Anybody got this error in the past ? If so, would you have an idea why there is a timeout ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Resolved, accepted answer.

In order to help everyone in the future, I will explain how I fixed the issue : Simply make sure to validate before opening `OpenTok` that you actually have the user's device permission for microphone, otherwise it might crash the app. Display a dialog until you allow them to do so in this specific case when you use `Nativescript`. Cannot confirm if happening with other frameworks!

Comment: Thanks, requesting Manifest.permission.CAMERA and Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO resolved this bug